# How to change owner and permissions of a folder in desktop

Tags: nautilus, permissions, files, root

The problem is that the folder directory is `/home/marek/Desktop/Tekkitserver/3.1.1` and root has all but 5 file ownership and permissions what are inside it.

It all happened after I launched tekkit server `.bat` file trough terminal and when I opened folder with "home folder" I saw that freshly created files are in total root access.

And none of the `sudo nautilus` commands worked, because the folder was unreachable for nautilus.
I was able to see no child folder even whit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and I have troubles with `chown`. My user name is Marek Parbo (`marek`) and I am an administrator.

And I know that this question is recently asked, but i really didn't understood it at all. I have experience with `sudo nautilus` because Root was so defensive that and freshly formatted SD card was only permissioned to root and i got rid of it whit `sudo nautilus`.

However, this time i can't use it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please remember to [format your post properly](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help). This assures you have a high quality questions, which will receive the high quality answers it deserves! Thanks and good luck!

Comment: Well, what are your troubles with `chown` and how exactly does `sudo nautilus` (which is discouraged for many reasons, btw - use `gksu nautilus` if you *really* need a root `nautilus` instance) not work?

Answer (score 4):

You can set permissions with the `chown` command. the `-R` option will set the permissions not only to the folder which you are setting the permissions on, but on all its contents as well.

from what I can gather, you need to set the folder's permission to you own account. to do this, execute the following command:

```
sudo chown -R marek:marek /home/marek/Desktop/Tekkitserver/3.1.1
```

Hope this does the trick. and please try to be more specific when you ask these questions...