# Wordpress permissions problem on apache2 server

Tags: server, virtualbox, permissions, apache2, mysql

I have a windows 7 system. 

On this system i am running a  `VM Virtual box LAMP Server` with Ubuntu 12.04,apache2, mysql and phpmyadmin... which is accessable via the internet.

I installed Wordpress CMS and it is working ok. I am able to add new posts, pages, and change themes.

When i attempt to upload media i get the following error

```
file391.jpg has failed to upload due to an error
Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2013/11. Is its parent directory writable by the server?*
```

When i go to the parent directory and look at the permissions i notice that the ownership of the folder is `root`.

Do i change owner?
Should i create a new user or user group called worpress and give it ownership???

Not sure how best to do this on a **Web server**.

Comment: see this post to change ownership of a folder http://askubuntu.com/questions/235296/how-to-change-owner-and-permissions-of-a-folder-in-desktop

Answer (score 3):

Apache2 is using the group www-data. You may want to add your current user into the www-data group by executing : `sudo useradd -g www-data username`.

Alternatively, you can do a recursive chown to the web root folder. To do this, issue the following command : `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www`

Comment: how do i know what group apache2 is using???

Comment: Ubuntu (and Debian) uses www-data as default user and group for apache2 by default. You can specify other users to join the www-data group though. You may want to check the contents of the umbrella file `apache2.conf` which will have something like `User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}` and `Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}`.

Comment: You can also use `apache2ctl -S` to display your current setup.